# How to implement One-To-Many relationship between non-primary keys?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables/entities: hotels, room types and rooms. Each hotel has multiple room types (single, double, etc), and each room type has multiple rooms associated.

```
CREATE TABLE hotels(
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   hotel_id UUID NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE room_types(
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   hotel_id UUID NOT NULL,
   room_type_id UUID NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY(hotel_id) REFERENCES hotels(hotel_id)
);

CREATE TABLE rooms(
   id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   room_type_id UUID NOT NULL,
   room_id UUID NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY(room_type_id) REFERENCES room_types(room_type_id)
);
```

Moreover, my assignment is to create these tables in a way that they reflect history of changes of each entity, for example

```
hotels
---------------------------------
| id | hotel_id | hotel_name
---------------------------------
| 1  | 501      | 'Grand Royale' 
| 2  | 501      | 'Grand-Royale'    -- change name
| 3  | 501      | 'Grand Royale 5*' -- change name
| 4  | 256      | 'Ocean Blue'

room_types
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | hotel_id | room_type_id   | room_name
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 501      | 44             | 'Single'
| 2  | 501      | 44             | 'Single Standard' -- change name
```

Same applies to room types and rooms. So I have primary key `id` which only reflects the number of a record, while every property (name, price, address, etc) can change. The only thing that doesn't change are unique ids `hotel_id`, `room_type_id` and `room_id`

I was able to do all of these while using plain java.sql.*, but now I need to rework the project with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate, and I am totally lost on how to map it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotels")
public class Hotel { 
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel")
   private Set<RoomType> roomTypes; // ???

   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "room_types")
public class RoomType {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id", referencedColumn = "id") // ???
   private Hotel hotel;
   ...
}
```

Comment: You are repeating data inside the table and that's a bad practice. Maybe create another table named 'room_changes' and add the changes of every room there to have a record of every one?

Answer (score 0):

How about this mapping?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotels")
public class Hotel { 
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "hotel_id, nullable = false, unique = true)
   private Long hotelId;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotel")
   private Set<RoomType> roomTypes;

   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "room_types")
public class RoomType {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id", referencedColumn = "hotel_id")
   private Hotel hotel;
   ...
}
```